# How to do an interruptable wait on a BlockingCollection<T> instance?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

Simple scenario - I want to block on a `BlockingCollection<T>` (if it is empty). On the other hand I want to block on a ManualResetEvent object used to signal when the thread needs to be terminated.

I understand that there is no way to use `WaitHandle.WaitAny` because blocking on a `BlockingCollection<T>` returns an item at the same time and does not fit easily into the API dictated by `WaitHandle.WaitAny`.

The simplest way I can think of is to block on a `BlockingCollection<T>` with a timeout and then wait with 0 timeout on the wait handle, something like this:

```
ManualResetEvent term = ...;
BlockingCollection<T> coll = ...;
while (true)
{
  T obj;
  bool found = coll.TryTake(out obj, 500);
  if (term.WaitOne(0))
  {
    break;
  }
  if (found)
  {
    // process the obj
  }
}
```

But I have a feeling there should be a more elegant solution, maybe using something else instead of a `BlockingCollection<T>`?

Any ideas are welcome.

**EDIT 1**

I am OK with moving away from MRE to using Cancellation Tokens, if that what it takes to have a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can implement your own `BlockingCollection<T>`-like wrapper using a semaphore (indicating the item count of the collection), then call `WaitHandle.WaitAny` on the semaphore and your manual reset event.

Comment: You should really use a `CancellationToken` as a way of signaling cancellation to a unit of work, not a MRE.

Comment: I'd take a look at [GetConsumingEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395014(v=vs.110).aspx) and supply a `CancellationToken` as Servy suggests.

Comment: You could simply call CompleteAdding() in the producer.  The consumer throws on a Take() call after the last item was received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option would be to use a `CancellationToken` (which you signal through a `CancellationTokenSource`) instead of `ManualResetEvent` (as was suggested in comments) combined with `GetConsumingEnumerable`:

```
var blockingCollection = ...
foreach (var obj in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancellationToken))
{
    // process the obj
}
```

---

A different option that would both allow to use a construct similar to `ManualResetEvent` and would "block" asynchronously without wasting a thread is to use `TPL Dataflow`'s `BufferBlock` with an `AsyncManualResetEvent`:

```
AsyncManualResetEvent term = ...
BufferBlock<T> buffer = ...
var termTask = term.WaitAsync();
while (true)
{
    var receiveTask = buffer.ReceiveAsync();
    if (termTask == await Task.WhenAny(receiveTask, termTask))
    {
        break;
    }

    T obj = await receiveTask;
    // process the obj
}
```

You can write you own `AsyncManualResetEvent` based on Stephen Toub's : [Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 1: AsyncManualResetEvent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266920.aspx) or use the one in Visual Studio SDK: [AsyncManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asyncmanualresetevent.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

CancellationTokenSource is what you need; plug this into a console app and call it.

```
private static void DoSomeWork()
{
    BlockingCollection<int> coll = new BlockingCollection<int>();
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((s) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread started. Waiting for item or cancellation.");
        try
        {
            var x = coll.Take(source.Token);
            Console.WriteLine("Take completed.");
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Take cancelled. IsCancellationRequested={0}", source.IsCancellationRequested);
        }
    });
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to cancel wait.");
    Console.ReadLine();
    source.Cancel(false);
    Console.WriteLine("Cancel sent. Press Enter to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This assumes he's able to change the types using this method from using an MRE to use a CancellationToken.  That may not be an option.